# Microsoft Excel cannot access the file

Tags: php, com

> Microsoft Excel cannot access the file
>
> 'C:\xxx\test.xls'. There are several possible reasons: • The file name
>   or path does not exist. • The file is being used by another program. •
>   The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently
>   open workbook.

I followed this steps

[link](http://www.figured-it-out.com/figured-out.php?sid=24)

Also I included the extesion "php_com_dotnet.dll" in php.ini.

I have Zend Server CE with php 5.3.14

The issue persist when I reboot the computer.

code::

```
$file   = "C:\\xxx\\test.xls";

try {
    $excel = new COM("Excel.Application") or die ("ERROR: Unable to instantaniate COM!\r\n");
    $excel->Visible = true;

    $Workbook = $excel->Workbooks->Open($file) or die("ERROR: Unable to open " . $file . "!\r\n");
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
```

Comment: check if $file  = "C:\\xxx\\test.xls"; path is correct.

Comment: maybe you don't have permission to that path, place the excel file in the same directory as your script and test again

Answer (score 0):

Things to consider:

Have you checked the permissions of the file? I'm assuming "xxx" is a placeholder for the proper folder name as well?

Do you have file open by something else?  Excel perhaps?  Excel will grab the file and "lock" it down from use by other things.

What user is the web server running as?  Can it access that path?

Comment: Yes, the xxx is the proper folder ($file   = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\dumps\\test.xls";) but also I tried in the same folder where the script is placed and I got the message (could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct. If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted). All the users have full permisions. The script is running locally and none files are opened by excels I checked it.

Answer (score 0):

try the answer from this guy named  Aardigspook
 in https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1182105-excel-cannot-access-the-file-2.html

The problem is a 'Name' . Go to the 'Formulas' tab, click 'Name Manager' and scroll down to the entry named 'special'. It refers to '--filepath--/[xxxxx.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A'. Delete this, or amend it to a reference you have/want, and the error should be gone.

-captain hair.

Answer (score -1):

After searching for a week and 3 times a new office 365 installation, my solution was to replace my faulty Micro-SD adapter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).